# SQL Query behavior

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm bogged in trying to figure out why query a is returning different records than query b.  Both queries have seemingly same purpose yet a is returning 500 and b 3500.

this is query a:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ODE.OrderBillToID
FROM    APTIFY.dbo.vwVwOrderDetailsKGExtended  ODE
WHERE ProductID IN (2022, 1393)
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ODE.OrderStatus)) <> 'Cancelled'
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ODE.OrderType)) <> 'Cancellation'
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ODE.cancellationStatus)) <> 'FULLY CANCELLED'
UNION
SELECT  DISTINCT ID
FROM    APTIFY.dbo.vwPersons WHERE City = 'A'
UNION 
SELECT  DISTINCT RecordID 
FROM    APTIFY.dbo.vwTopicCodeLinks WHERE TopicCodeID = 16 AND Value = 'Yes,     Please'
```

query b:

```
SELECT
    APTIFY..vwPersons.ID
FROM 
    APTIFY..vwPersons 
WHERE    
    ( APTIFY..vwPersons.ID   IN  (  
              SELECT
                   vwMeetingRegistrants.ID
              FROM
                   APTIFY.dbo.vwMeetings   vwMeetings
                   INNER JOIN APTIFY.dbo.vwMeetingRegistrants   vwMeetingRegistrants   
                        ON vwMeetings.ID=vwMeetingRegistrants.ActualMeetingID              WHERE
                        vwMeetings.ProductID  = 2022
 ) 
OR
     APTIFY..vwPersons.ID   IN  (  
              SELECT
                   vwMeetingRegistrants.ID
              FROM
                   APTIFY.dbo.vwMeetings   vwMeetings
                   INNER JOIN APTIFY.dbo.vwMeetingRegistrants   vwMeetingRegistrants   
                        ON vwMeetings.ID=vwMeetingRegistrants.ActualMeetingID              WHERE
                        vwMeetings.ProductID  = 1393
 ) 
OR
     APTIFY..vwPersons.City = N'Albany' )
OR
((
     APTIFY..vwPersons.ID   IN  (  
              SELECT
                   RecordID
              FROM
                   APTIFY.dbo.vwTopicCodeLinks     vwTopicCodeLinks
              WHERE
                        vwTopicCodeLinks.TopicCodeID  = 16
 ) 
AND
     APTIFY..vwPersons.ID   IN  (  
              SELECT
                   RecordID
              FROM
                   APTIFY.dbo.vwTopicCodeLinks     vwTopicCodeLinks
              WHERE
                        vwTopicCodeLinks.Value  = N'Yes, Please'
 ) )
)
```

vwMeetingsRegistrants from the b query are producing the same records as orderkgdetailsextended from query.  I cannot see ANY difference in those queries - which perhaps shows my lack of understanding the query behaviour.
BIG Thanks for any points guys! :)

Comment: Your first query has checks for `'Cancelled'`, `'Cancellation'`and `'FULLY CANCELLED'` which the second query does not, and it checks for `City = 'A'` instead of `City = N'Albany'` and I guess there are more differences. Did you check those?

Comment: Thanks Peter for getting back to me! 
Yes you are right!  however, city 'Albany' and city 'A' are the same as 'Cancelled' Cancellation and Fully Cancelled are the same are records from meetings registrants view which is used in the query B.  

After extensive amount of trial and error I sort of think this is related to OR and AND's in the query B but I don't understand or see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it came out, incorrectly structured query is a result of badly configured application, Aptify.